# How does "User in Random Percentile" work in Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-remote-config

I have two questions regarding Firebase Remote config:

1. If I assign 50% value to it then does it do A/B test over 50-50 percent of my total audience ?
2. If I have two parameters in remote config, and each has a different value for "User In Random Percentile" then does firebase assign Random value once and passes same value to both parameters or for each two parameters it calculates two times?

Comment: Here you can read about Parameters and Conditions [Parameters and Conditions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/parameters?authuser=0#rule_types)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Yep. Create a condition that targets 50% of users:

[image]

and then in your parameter, use that condition along with a default value:

[image]

50% of users will trigger the condition, the other 50% will fall back to default. A more in-depth example of 50% testing can be found in the "Creating Your First A/B Test" section of [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/147204/firebase-tutorial-ios-ab-testing).

2. It depends on how you configure it. As stated in [the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/parameters#rule_types):

> You can use a single key across rules to consistently address the same
>   app instances within given percentage ranges. Or, you can select a new
>   randomly-assigned group of app instances for a given percentage range
>   by creating a new key.

If it's unclear how to change the key, here is a screenshot:

[image: randomization key screenshot]