# Does a user's randomly assigned parameter value in Firestore Remote Config persist between applications that use that value?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-remote-config

I'm using the "User in random percentile" condition in a parameter key in Firestore's Remote Config to assign 50% of users to see a new feature in our app. I'm using this same parameter key in two applications that a user can flow between (one is a Chrome extension, the other is a web app). Will the user's randomly assigned value persist between the two applications? If not, is there a way to set it up so that it does?

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does "User in Random Percentile" work in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44382378/how-does-user-in-random-percentile-work-in-firebase)

Answer (score 1):

Heard back from Firebase support: The value does not persist between applications (i.e. is not set on a per-Firebase-user basis).